# ESS error Autoloading failed to define function compilation--ensure-parse

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I just upgraded to latest version of ESS using package manager for Ubuntu 12.04.   Emacs alone seems to work fine, but Emacs does not work with ESS (Emacs Speaks Statistics).  Upon start up of ESS, I get the message:

Error in post-command-hook: (error Autoloading failed to define function compilation--ensure-parse).

How can I fix this?

Below is my rather brief .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and gv") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-pdf "Evince") (output-html "xdg-open"))))
 '(scroll-bar-mode (quote right)))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "white" :foreground "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 117 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono")))))


;; ********* Beginning of customization ******************

;; assign word-wrapping mode
(global-visual-line-mode 1)  ; 1=on, 0=off

;; speed up function evaluation
(setq ess-eval-visibly-p nil)

;; "Set font-lock colors to Richard Heiberger's wheat color scheme."
  ;; (set-foreground-color "Black")
  ;; (set-background-color "Wheat")
  ;; (set-face-foreground 'modeline "Wheat")
  ;; (set-face-background 'modeline "Sienna")

  ;; (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "Firebrick")
  ;; (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-function-name-face "Blue")
  ;; (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-keyword-face "Purple")
  ;; (if (eq font-lock-reference-face 'font-lock-constant-face )
  ;;     (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-constant-face "Brown")
  ;;   (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-reference-face "Brown"))
  (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-string-face "VioletRed")
  ;; (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-type-face "Sienna")
  ;; (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-variable-name-face "Black")

; count words in latex docs
(defun latex-word-count ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "/usr/bin/texcount "
    "-inc "; texcount option (set to count documents included via \input)
    (buffer-file-name))))

; that's [ctrl-c w] as the hotkey
(global-set-key (quote [f6]) 'latex-word-count)


;; ********* End of customization ******************
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same error message started appearing on my system a few days ago. Following a suggestion from [this](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/ESS-error-Autoloading-failed-to-define-function-compilation-ensure-parse-td370351.html) forum, I upgraded Emacs 23 to 24, and this fixed the problem. Apparently (according to the forum), many of the latest features of ess only work on Emacs 24, so if you use Emacs to write R code, it's a good idea to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Thank you.   Upgrading to Emacs 24 solved my problem also.